# Deploy database project (.dbproj) using powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, msbuild

I want to deploy a database project "database.dbproj" (for example) using powershell. So far, I tried to deploy project using following methods,

> $msbuild = 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe'
>
> $option1 = @(' /t:reBuild,deploy /p:TargetConnectionString="Data
>   Source=(local)\SQL2008R2;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;"
>   /p:TargetDatabase=test "C:\TEMP\SVN\6000\Database\Database.dbproj"')
>
> & $msbuild $option1

And

> $test1 = @('
>   /target:Build,deploy','C:\TEMP\SVN\6000\Database\Database.dbproj','/property:TargetConnectionString="Data
>   Source=(local)\SQL2008R2;Integrated
>   Security=True;Pooling=False;"','/property:TargetDatabase=test')
>
> & $msbuild $test1

and

> $test2 = $msbuild +"" + $option1
>
> Invoke-Expression $test2

But in all cases it doesn't do anything. I mean if I debug the code then I can see that this pointer reaches to this command and then simply moves to next line of command without doing anything. 
I have similar Batch script, and it works just fine. So I am sure that it is some noob mistake that is causing this issue. What is wrong I am doing here ?

Thanks,
Jack

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" -ArgumentList "/t:reBuild,deploy /p:TargetConnectionString=`"Data Source=(local)\SQL2008R2;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;`" /p:TargetDatabase=test `"C:\TEMP\SVN\6000\Database\Database.dbproj`""
```